# Dynamically create pages using textview, scrollview, and pagecontrol in swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, scrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a string content that varies in size.  Basically what I need is a book effect.

I am able to store this information in a textview but what I want is for it to wrap (to a next page) when it reaches the end of my textview container and for the user to be able to flip through the pages like flipping through a book.

I would also like the pages to have page numbers instead of dots like a pagecontrol would have.

I'm almost certain that this can be done in scrollview but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: I'm able to add the string in a textview.  I added a scrollview and pagecontrol.  Right now it just creates one page that scrolls up and down and a pagecontrol that stays in one page because I can't figure out how to split the content into pages once it hits the end of my textview container.